# Some Varnish Requests Getting Past my Block.vcl

Tags: amazon-web-services, load-balancing, varnish, varnish-vcl

Recently dealt with a botnet running a sub-domain brute force/crawling script. Would run through the alphabet & numbers sequentially, which resulted in a minor nuisance and small load increase for legitimate traffic.

For example, hitting a.domain, b.domain, .., 9.domain, aa.domain, .., a9.domain. etc.

Obviously, this is quite stupid and fortunately it only originated from a few IP's at a time and the website in question was behind multiple auto-scaling load balancers. Attacks were stopped grabbing the X-Forwarded-For address from Varnish, detection was scripted via the subdomain attempts and the IP added to a remote blocklist which would be regularly refreshed and added into a Block.vcl on all Varnish servers, voila.

This worked well, detecting and taking care of things within a couple minutes each time. However it was noted that in the space of time after blocking an brute IP and applying blockage, 99.9% of the traffic would stop but the occasional requests from the blocked IP would still manage to get through. Not enough to cause a fuss, but more raise the question why? As I don't understand why a request at the varnish level would still make it through when hitting the reject on IP rule of my Block.vcl?

Is there some inherent limitation that might have come into play here which would allow a small number of requests through? Maybe based on the available resources or sheer number of requests per second hitting Varnish overwhelming it ever so slightly?

Resource wise the web servers seemed fine so I'm unsure. Any ideas?

Comment: Whats your Varnish config?

Comment: @Max it is pretty standard i believe, just including a list of IP's to block:  
`// Add block list
include "block-list.vcl";`  
----  
`acl block {
    ip;
}`  
----  
`// Block IPs in block list  
if ( client.ip ~ block ) {   
     error 444 "";  
}`